# Import error add_lazy_relation when using django-taggit

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add tags functionality to my django application. I want to use taggit app, but when I try to makemigrations I am getting an error:

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import (add_lazy_relation, ManyToManyRel,
ImportError: cannot import name 'add_lazy_relation'
```

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

I'm using: Django==2.2.8, django-taggit==0.17.1

Answer (score 4):

The error message mentions `add_lazy_relation`, which [was removed in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0)

You are using django-taggit [0.17.1](https://pypi.org/project/django-taggit/0.17.1/), which was released in 2015. You can't expect it to support Django 2.2 (released April 2019). Try upgrading to the latest version, currently 1.2.0.